# gin-contrib/cors returns 404

Tags: go, cors, go-gin

I've got a golang REST API, which implements `gin-contrib/cors`. But when I call a POST request the preflight request (OPTIONS) returns a 404 result.

Here's a snippet of the implementation:

```
engine := gin.New()
group := engine.Group("/api/v1")

// Recovery middleware recovers from any panics and writes a 500 if there was one.
group.Use(gin.Recovery())

// Set cors and db middleware
engine.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"},
    AllowMethods:     []string{"*"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"*"},
    AllowCredentials: true,     
    MaxAge: 12 * time.Hour,
}))

// Register routes
group.POST("/customers", ctrl.SendRequest)
```

Comment: Can I add the main code? There is not enough information.

Comment: Add your main code and HTTP request curl args will be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

```
engine := gin.New()

engine.Use(func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE")

    if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        c.AbortWithStatus(204)
        return
    }

    c.Next()
})
```

make sure you add CORS middleware before you adding group

Comment: Unfortunately, the wildcard (`*`) is incompatible with credentialed requests.

Answer (score 5):

I had EXACTLY the same problem, but positioning the 'group' was not the issue.

here is my code with the problem code commented out and replaced with manual cors....

```
// router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
//  // AllowAllOrigins: true,
//  AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"},
//  AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
//  AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin", "Accept", "Content-Type", "Content-Length", "Accept-Encoding", "X-CSRF-Token", "Authorization", "ResponseType"},
//  ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
//  AllowCredentials: true,
//  MaxAge:           12 * time.Hour,
// }))

router.Use(func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, ResponseType, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE")

    if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        c.AbortWithStatus(204)
        return
    }
    c.Next()
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your cors middleware to your engine before you create your group. Because gin copies all the middlewares added to the engine to the group when you create the group. So if you add it afterwards to the engine, it won't be part of the group.

```golang
engine := gin.New()

// Set cors and db middleware
engine.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"},
    AllowMethods:     []string{"*"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"*"},
    AllowCredentials: true,     
    MaxAge: 12 * time.Hour,
}))

group := engine.Group("/api/v1")

// Recovery middleware recovers from any panics and writes a 500 if there was one.
group.Use(gin.Recovery())

// Register routes
group.POST("/customers", ctrl.SendRequest)
```

Comment: Sound logic but doesn't work :( I moved it in front of ```gin.new()```, but still got 404 responses

Comment: I think this actually did the trick for me. I now receive the headers trough nginx reverse proxy. Thank you!

Comment: What if you only want to apply the CORS middleware to `/api/v1/`? There should be a way to do this with Gin.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try adding cors without `gin-contrib/cors` middleware. 
I tried `gin-contrib/cors` faced the same issue then added the cors header manually

```
router := gin.New()
router.Use(func(context *gin.Context) {
    context.Writer.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    context.Writer.Header().Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "10000")
    context.Writer.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS")
    context.Writer.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization,Content-Type,Accept")
    context.Next()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of group should not matter here.

How did you send the `OPTIONS` request? I'm assuming that your request do not contain an `Origin` header, hence the CORS middleware assumes that the "request is not a CORS request". The relevant source code is at [config.go#L58-L62](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors/blob/5f50d4fb4e0306dcacc6f8e9bea2dcee784dbbdf/config.go#L58-L62):

```golang
    origin := c.Request.Header.Get("Origin")
    if len(origin) == 0 {
        // request is not a CORS request
        return
    }
```

To properly test if the CORS middleware works, try the following curl command:

```sh
$ curl -i -X OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/login -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type" -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000"

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Content-Length,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 43200
Date: Sun, 27 Mar 2022 17:55:49 GMT
```